# Facebook graph API & php SDK performance issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to duplicate a public facebook page timeline on website, using the **php SDK**. Script works fine except for the execution time that is pretty long.
Searching around i've read that facebook API can be pretty slow sometimes, by the way i'd like some help figuring out if my script is fine or if some improvement can be done for a faster execution time.

Here's my simplified code :

```
    require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => 'myappid',
      'app_secret' => 'appsecret',
      'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
    ]);
    $request = '/11239244970/posts?access_token=my_acces_token_';
    $search = $fb->get($request);
    $raw= $search->getGraphEdge();
    $data = $raw->asArray();
    $results = [];
    foreach($data as $el){
      if(isset($el['message'])){
        try{
          $messaggio = $el['message'];
          $creato =  $el['created_time'];
          $newDate = $creato->format('d/m/Y');
          $laData = str_replace("/","-",$newDate);
          $id = $el['id'];
          $evento = $el['story'];
          $atch = $id.'/attachments?access_token=my_acces_token_';
          $xx = $fb->get($atch);
          $yy= $xx->getGraphEdge();
          $atachment = $yy->asArray();
          $like = $id.'/likes?summary=true&access_token=my_acces_token_';
          $likes = $fb->get($like);
          $likes = $likes->getGraphEdge();
          $like_count = $likes->getTotalCount();
          $atachments = [];
          }
        catch(Exception $e) {

        }
          //$likes = $likes->asArray();
          foreach($atachment as $at){
              if(isset($at['subattachments'])){
                $atchs = $at['subattachments'];
                foreach($atchs as $atx){
                  $atachments[] = $atx['media']['image']['src'];
                }
              }else if(isset($at['media']['image'])){
                  $atachments[] = $at['media']['image']['src'];
                }

            }

          $temp = [$messaggio,$laData,$evento,$like_count,$atachments];
          $results[]= $temp;
      }

    }
    print_r($results);
```

That piece of code grabs the last (i think by default) 25 posts and check if they have  message and atachments.

As i said this code works fine, it is getting what i need except for execution time that is about 5 to 10 seconds. 
Any suggestions or improvement? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this on every page load? You need to cache the data on your end, otherwise you will run into the API request limits very soon anyway.

Comment: At the moment yes im doing calls on every page load, i was already thinking to cache data on backend, how much is request limit? is like hourly/daily? because even if i cache i have to make requests for check new post, old post deleted post ecc.. and also cronjob for update the data

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting